# How can I make ASP MVC4 / Web API completely ignore routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set up mapping in my SPA application. The basic mapping uses Web API and the following:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "spa",
        "{section}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { section = @"home|admin" });
```

When the user enters /home/abc then it calls the home controller and the index method.

How can I make it so that requests like the following with **three** parts to them

```
/home/abc/def
/home/overview/123
/home/xx/12
/home/anything/anything
```

are completely ignored ? Note that I don't actually need the id parameter but I left it here as it seems to make no difference and still calls the home controller and index method.

Comment: Where is Web Api? When You define web api routes You should write: config.Routes.MapHttpRoute

Comment: I have other Web Api routes not shown here. The all start with /api

Comment: Can You provide more info: why are You need to ignore /home/something/something? Seems like You're facing other problem which mabby can be solved if You explain exactly what You need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wildcard after ignoring `home/acb/`.  Something like:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("home/abc/{*pathinfo}");
```

That should ignore anything with a `/` after `home/abc`

Comment: I need to accept /home/abc and ignore /home/abc/def so would I need to add one more wildcard from what you suggest ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question at first.  I updated my answer with what I think you need.

Answer (score 2):

It could be take as a workaround..

Write one Constraint class using **IRouteConstraint** and add that constraint for **id** parameter.
Then write your own logic there to check the URL Segments passed in request and you can return TRUE/FALSE according to your URL Requirement...

Make sense???

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have deleted the default route:

```
//routes.MapRoute(
//    name: "Default",
//    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
//    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe just add them to be ignored

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute(route1)
```

Comment: Can you show me what route1 would look like? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: You should explain what route1 will look like

Comment: Do you need to ignore all routes except particular controller and action accepting int id?